# Splitting range into sub-ranges

Tags: c++, c++11, range, move, move-semantics

I have a container std::vector and I would like to efficiently split it into sub-ranges with x items in each. The original container is not needed so the items should be moved and not copied into the sub-ranges.

I've managed to do the splitting using copying, however I'm unsure how to do it with move assignments?

```
    range.insert(range.end(), new_items.begin(), new_items.end());
    while(range.size() >= x)
    {
        sub_ranges.push_back(std::vector<int>(range.begin(), range.begin() + x));
        range = std::vector<int>(range.begin() + x, range.end());
    }
```

EDIT:

Some progress... still not quite there, and a bit ugly

```
    while(range.size() >= x)
    {
        std::vector<short> sub_range(x); // Unnecessary allocation?
        std::move(range.begin(), range.begin() + x, sub_range.begin());
        sub_ranges_.push_back(std::move(sub_range));

        std::move(range.begin() + x, range.end(), range.begin());
        range.resize(range.size() - x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::make_move_iterator` in `<iterator>` to wrap your iterator into a `move_iterator`. This iterator will `std::move` the result of dereferencing its base iterator, allowing that to be moved elsewhere.

```
// assuming I understand your code, which I don't
range.insert(range.end(), new_items.begin(), new_items.end());
while(range.size() >= x)
{
    auto first = std::make_move_iterator(range.begin());
    auto last = std::make_move_iterator(range.begin() + x);

    sub_ranges.push_back(std::vector<int>(first, last));
    range = std::vector<int>(range.begin() + x, range.end());
}
```

---

EDIT: And like you found, there's a mapping between `std::move()` and `make_move_iterator`:

```
std::move(first, last, out); // is the same as
std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(first), std::make_move_iterator(last), out);
```

So which you find cleaner is up to you. (The first one, to me.)

Answer (score 3):

One question: have you ever heard of the `View` concept.

The idea is that instead of actually moving the data, you just create a "view" (Proxy pattern)  that will restrict / change your perception of it.

For example, for a range, a very simple implementation would be:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct Range
{
  Iterator mBegin, mEnd;
};
```

`Boost.Range` offers a fat version, with a lot of things.

The advantages are numerous in this case. among which:

- A single `vector`, thus better memory locality
- The split is easy, and doesn't involve any move / copy of the data

Here is the `split` with this method:

```
typedef Range<std::vector<int>::iterator> range_type;

std::vector<range_type> split(std::vector<int> const& range, size_t x)
{
  std::vector<range_type> subRanges;
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = range.begin(), end = range.end();
       it != end; it += std::min(x, (size_t)std::distance(it,end)))
  {
    subRanges.push_back(range_type(it,end));
  }
  return subRanges;
}
```

Of course, this only works if you can keep the `range` object around.

---

Regarding your original algorithm: the use of a `while` loop is spurious here, and forces you to use much more `move`s than necessary. The `for` loop I crafted should be much better in this regard.

Comment: Is `subRanges.push_back(range_type(it,end));` correct? There does not seem to be a ctor for `range_type` that takes two iterators.